# Submitting short version of an under review journal article in conference

Tags: publications, journals, ethics, conference, self-plagiarism

I have an article under review in a journal which is taking very long review time. I want to submit a short version in a conference citing that detailed version is under review in XYZ journal. I know the other way round is common practice. 
 
 I want to know if it is an acceptable practice in computer science area?